# Create menu by removing duplicates from JSON data

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

Build dynamic menu from multiple metadata files

I have a JavaScript loop that displays the images from an NFT collection and uses the class names to create a filter. Currently the filter menu is hard-coded, but I would like to build it dynamically from the metadata.

```
var loopFunction = function(dataIsLoading) { // the loop
    
    let itemID = "";
    var itemSource = "Azuki";
    var itemURI = "https://ikzttp.mypinata.cloud/ipfs/QmQFkLSQysj94s5GvTHPyzTxrawwtjgiiYS2TBLgrvw8CW/"
    
    for (let i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        
        itemID += [i];
        
        $.getJSON(itemURI+i, function(data) {
            
            // alert(data.name);
            var eachItem = "";
            
            var itemName = data.name;
            var traits = data.attributes;
            var classes = "";
            var traitList = "";
            
            $.each(data.attributes,function(index,entry) { // k (key), v (value) / i (index), e (entry)
                
                var str = entry.value;
                str = str.replace(/ /g, '');
                
                classes += '' + entry.trait_type + '' + str + ' ';
                traitList += '<span class="item-trait-type">' + entry.trait_type + ':</span> ' + str + '<br />';
            });
            
            eachItem += '<div class="cstm-grid-item cstm-width-1-2 cstm-width-large-1-3 cstm-width-x-large-1-4 ' +classes+'" id="'+i+'">';
                eachItem += '<div class="img-placeholder">';
                    eachItem += '<img class="lazy" data-src="https://ikzttp.mypinata.cloud/ipfs/QmYDvPAXtiJg7s8JdRBSLWdgSphQdac8j1YuQNNxcGE1hg/'+i+'.png" width="100%" height="auto" />';
                eachItem += '</div>';
                eachItem += '<span class="item-title">'+itemName+'</span>';
                eachItem += '<p class="item-traits">'
                    eachItem += traitList;
                eachItem += '</p>'
            eachItem += '</div>';
            
            $('.cstm-grid').append(eachItem);
        });
    }
};
```

I have all of the data, but building the menu is difficult to do dynamically without the the menu having duplicate values. I just need the single base category (trait type) and the single values for that trait type. The final output should look something like:

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <h2>Trait Type 1</h2><!-- the category -->
        <ul>
            <li>red</li><!-- the value -->
            <li>blue</li><!-- the value -->
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
        <h2>Trait Type 2</h2><!-- the category -->
        <ul>
            <li>sunglasses</li><!-- the value -->
            <li>hat</li><!-- the value -->
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: There is probably a much more elegant way of doing this, but my JavaScript knowledge is limited. Essentially the display is working perfectly, it's the dynamic menu that I can't work out.

Comment: your desired output has exactly the structure you need to group your values by trait type.

Comment: Yes, the output has the right structure, but I'm trying to build a dynamic menu without duplicate values. Loop through, create a list with each trait category, and the traits that are nested within that category.